# ajax for autosearch not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

This is the code below which works fine when i select one from the suggestion list but when i press search button it doesnt work please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stream;

function suggest(inputString) {
    if (inputString.length == 0 || inputString == " ") {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
        stream = inputString;
        $('#listings').addClass('load');
        $.post("autosuggest.php", { queryString: "" + inputString + "" }, function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                $('#listings').removeClass('load');
            }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#listings').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 100);
    stream = thisValue;
}
function go() {
    $('#listings').val(stream);
}
</script>
```

here is the html part

```
<div class="search">
 <form id="form" action="search_results.php" method="POST" class="new-search">
  <div class="field" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" size="25" value="" name="search_term" id="listings" onkeyup="suggest(this.value);"
        onblur="fill();" class="" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="search" onclick="go();">
        Search</button>
    <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
        <div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Its not working when i hit the search button. the POST method is not passing the name.

Comment: inspect your network what is ajax status...?

Comment: How should it work when you press the search button? And paste a little of your php code also.

Comment: You need to remove that `onblur="fill();"`

Comment: `id="search"` is of `type="submit"` and `go()` does not call `event.preventDefault()` so clicking the button reloads the page before the other code can run ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your button with `id="search"` is of `type="submit"` and `go()` does not call `preventDefault()` so clicking the button submits the form and reloads the page before the other code can run

Also, embrace event handlers and remove all the js call attributes from the html

Updated, your code might look something like the below, though I cant fully test it on end

JavaScript:

```
   <script>
        $(function() {
            var stream;
            var $suggestions=$('#suggestions');
            var $listings= $('#listings');

            $('#search').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault()
                $('#listings').val(stream);
            });

            $listings.keyup(function() {
                var inputString=$(this).val();
                // use a custom timer to only make the call when the user stops typing
                keyupDelay(function(){
                    if (inputString.length == 0 || inputString == " ") {
                        $suggestions.fadeOut();
                    }
                    else {
                        $listings.addClass('load');
                        $.post("autosuggest.php", {
                            queryString: "" + inputString + ""
                        }, function(data) {
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                $suggestions.fadeIn();
                                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                                $listings.removeClass('load');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 1000 );
            });
            $listings.blur(function(){
                var thisValue =$(this).val();
                // $listings.val(thisValue); // .....this is equivalent to what you had but it doesnt make sense, you're setting its value to itself
                $suggestions.delay(1000).fadeOut();
                stream = thisValue;

            });
            //  function to handle the keyup timer stuff
            var keyupDelay = (function(){
                var timer = 0;
                return function(callback, ms){
                    clearTimeout (timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
                };
            })();
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
    <form id="form" action="search_results.php" method="POST" class="new-search">
        <div class="field" id="searchform">
            <input type="text" size="25" value="" name="search_term" id="listings" class="" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="search">Search</button>
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                <div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I did paste your above code but the button went unresponsive.....where should i paste this exactly ?

$('#search').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault() 
    $('#listings').val(stream);
}

Comment: @Dhaivat  It needs to be in an "on load" function like `$(function(){ });` so that it's called after the element is rendered on the page, edited above

Comment: alright search button is working perfect. but  now auto suggest isnt working now. Would be thankful if u have a look at my code.